# Four teams A, B, C, D are the only four remaining teams in a single-elimination tournament.

Tags: probability

Four teams A, B, C, D are the only four remaining teams in a single-elimination tournament. Each round consists of the teams playing in pairs with the winners of each game continuing to the next round. Assume that the teams are randomly paired.
a) Assume that each has an equal opportunity to winning the game, what is the probability that team A and team B will play each other in one of the two rounds?
b) Assume that team A has winning odds 60% vs. 40% to B or C or D, but all other pairs of teams have an equal opportunity to winning the game, what is the probability that team A and team B will play each other in one of the two rounds?

- I know there will be 3 separate cases but that is as far as I have gotten and I believe the probability for each case will be 1/3 but I don't know if that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint
There are two ways that A and B can play each other (assuming that I am interpreting the question correctly).

(1)
They are immediately paired together. 
What is the probability of this happening?

(2)
They are paired separately (again what are the chances) **and**
A and B **both win** (against their separate opponents) in the *preliminary* round.

Note, as I understand the question(s), if A and B play each other, the *outcome* is **irrelevant.**

Comment: If I understood what you said correctly, for part A the probability of A & B play one round is 1/3 and the probability of A & B play the second round is 1/6, so the probability of A and B play in one of 2 rounds is 1/2? For part B, the probability of A & B play one round is 1/3 and the probability of A & B play the second round is 1/5 so the probability of A & B play one of two rounds is 8/15?

Comment: @Sam Exactly, you nailed it.